# Use the stuff replace function in SQL Server 2008 to replace <div> tags and strings inside the div tags as well

Tags: sql-server

I am having a hard time using stuff / replace function to remove the existing div tags in the records and the string inside the divs as well.

Here is a sample record.

```
<p>  <span style="font: 16px/15.18px 돋움; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); text-transform: none; text-indent: 0px; letter-spacing: normal; word-spacing: 0px; float: none; display: inline !important; white-space: normal; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;">サンルイズ大広場は昔、</span><wbr style="font: 16px/15.18px 돋움; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); text-transform: none; text-indent: 0px; letter-spacing: normal; word-spacing: 0px; white-space: normal; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;" /><span style="font: 16px/15.18px 돋움; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); text-transform: none; text-indent: 0px; letter-spacing: normal; word-spacing: 0px; float: none; display: inline !important; white-space: normal; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;">イントラムロス地域の名前の中で一つを選んで作られたもので、</span><wbr style="font: 16px/15.18px 돋움; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); text-transform: none; text-indent: 0px; letter-spacing: normal; word-spacing: 0px; white-space: normal; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;" /><span style="font: 16px/15.18px 돋움; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); text-transform: none; text-indent: 0px; letter-spacing: normal; word-spacing: 0px; float: none; display: inline !important; white-space: normal; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;">カサマニラ、カサブランカ、カスウルタネタ、ロスヒタルコウス、</span><wbr style="font: 16px/15.18px 돋움; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); text-transform: none; text-indent: 0px; letter-spacing: normal; word-spacing: 0px; white-space: normal; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;" /><span style="font: 16px/15.18px 돋움; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); text-transform: none; text-indent: 0px; letter-spacing: normal; word-spacing: 0px; float: none; display: inline !important; white-space: normal; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;">エルヨーガ、フィリピノで作られた商業複合団地。</span></p>
```

(After this, someone injected the table records containing the following below.)

```
<div style="display:none"><h3>suprax 100mg 5ml suspension dosage</h3>suprax for gonorrhea <a href="http://www.dunshaughlinac.com/news-details.asp?id=112">suprax</a> buying suprax without a script</div><div style="display:none"><h3>suprax 400mg</h3>buy suprax online uk <a href="http://www.dunshaughlinac.com/news-details.asp?id=112">suprax</a> overnight suprax canada</div><div style="display:none"><h3>1-800-gambler.org</h3>call 1-800-gambler <a href="http://www.800gambler.org/">http://www.800gambler.org/</a> teen gambling</div><div class="inpspjdeq"><div style="display:none"><h3>buy clarithromycin no prescription</h3>buying biaxin <a href="http://www.geospatialworld.net/Event/View.aspx?EID=63#buyclarithromycin">order biaxin</a> buy discount clarithromycin</div></div><script type="text/javascript">xjswyvnyg=document.getElementsByClassName("inpspjdeq");for(stqxrhhl=0;stqxrhhl!=xjswyvnyg.length;++stqxrhhl){xjswyvnyg[stqxrhhl].style.visibility="hidden";}</script><div style="display:none"><h3>buy clarithromycin without prescription</h3>cheapest clarithromycin <a href="http://www.geospatialworld.net/Event/View.aspx?EID=63#buyclarithromycin">order biaxin 500mg</a> generic clarithromycin</div><div style="display:none"><h3>order biaxin tablets</h3>cheapest biaxin <a href="http://www.geospatialworld.net/Event/View.aspx?EID=63#buyclarithromycin">buy clarithromycin</a> cheapest clarithromycin</div><div style="display:none"><h3>buy clarithromycin australia</h3>order clarithromycin 500mg <a href="http://www.geospatialworld.net/Event/View.aspx?EID=63#buyclarithromycin">buy clarithromycin</a> buy discount biaxin</div><div style="display:none"><h3>order clarithromycin 500mg</h3>clarithromycin online <a href="http://www.geospatialworld.net/Event/View.aspx?EID=63#buyclarithromycin">buy biaxin 250mg</a> purchasing clarithromycin</div><div style="display:none"><h3>buy clarithromycin 500mg</h3>order clarithromycin 250mg <a href="http://www.geospatialworld.net/Event/View.aspx?EID=53">buy clarithromycin</a> buy biaxin usa</div><div style="display:none"><h3>buy biaxin pills</h3>buy clarithromycin usa <a href="http://www.geospatialworld.net/Event/View.aspx?EID=43">buy clarithromycin</a> buy clarithromycin without prescription</div>
```

As you can see there are numerous nested divs as well, and I am trying to use the stuff method to replace the following with an empty string ''.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're better off writing an application in some other language, so you have access to more text manipulating functionality and regex functionality (would take something like 30 minutes to develop this I would think). However - if really wanting to keep it in SQL, I would not do it in an one-line/in-line statement. I make a function which takes the string, and then while not at the end of the string - keep replacing in the string. This way you can make a parse method which can handle a bit more complex situations (such as your style attribute as well). But it's easier in an application

Answer (score 0):

I already found a solution to my problem

I used the replace and within the replace function, I used the substring method to take the piece of the record from the opening div tag to the closing div tag.

```
update tbSpot
set [ColumnName]=  replace([ColumnName], SUBSTRING([ColumnName], CHARINDEX('<div', [ColumnName]), 5000), '')
```

Now you can also replace the 5000 to any number / index of the character within your record as long as you can target the maximum index you wish.

Comment: I have found a completely perfect solution for this one, as found in the article  [here](http://basitaalishan.com/2014/02/23/removing-part-of-string-before-and-after-specific-character-using-transact-sql-string-functions/)